# How to load a url without webview in android?

Tags: android, webview, android-service

I want to load a url in the background after every 30 seconds (as a Service) in my app. I have to load url in my service class, as it has no layout, so webview is not suitable for this. What should I use to load url in background even when the app is closed ?

MyService.java class

```
public class MyService extends Service {
Activity activity ;

Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable runnable;
int delay = 7*1000;

public MyService(Activity activity){
    this.activity = activity ;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    handler.postDelayed( runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            loadURL();

            handler.postDelayed(runnable, delay);
        }
    }, delay);
    return START_STICKY ;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {

}

public void loadURL(){
    try{
        String id = activity.getIntent().getStringExtra("ID");
        URL url = new URL("http://localhost/att.php?id=" + id + "&status=&submit=Insert");
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    } catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(this, ""+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: "How to load a url without webview in android?" : use Glide or Volley library to get data

Comment: No, i just want to refresh that url through my app after every 30 seconds

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new WorkManager.

Basically you create a Worker class that extends from one of these:

Worker
CoroutineWorker
RxWorker
ListenableWorker

Then you declare it like this:

```
val mWorker = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<Worker>(15, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .addTag(WORK_TAG)
            .setConstraints(Constraints.Builder().setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED).build())
            .build()
```

And then enqueue unique work so that work manager doesn't start more of the same task:

```
  WorkManager.getInstance(context)
            .enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(WORK_TAG, ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP, locationWorker)
```

Using your code when you extend your Worker class to for example ListenableWorker, you override a startWork() function and in the body run:

```
 handler.postDelayed( runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            loadURL();

            handler.postDelayed(runnable, delay);
        }
    }, delay);
```

Comment: Where is the url loaded  ?

Comment: In the Worker class you should make the network call to your url.